Intersection of spheres in normed space
It is easy to proof the following result:

Let $X$ be a normed space. Then, two closed balls $B(x_1,r_1)$ and $B(x_2,r_2)$ intersect if, and only if, $||x_1-x_2|| \leq r_1+r_2$.

Now, my question is if, in general, it is also true that result but changing closed balls by spheres. If not, is it at least true in the finite-dimensional case?
Obviously, one implication is clearly true (if the spheres intersect the distance of the centers clearly satisfies the bound), but for the other implication I've being not able to prove it besides the euclidean case.
Edit: As pointed out in the comments, for the sphere case I forgot to state that it should also be satisfied that $||x_1-x_2|| \geq |r_1-r_2|$

Assuming by sphere you mean $\partial B$, where $\partial$ denotes the boundary:
Let $x_1 = x_2$ and $r_1 \neq r_2$, then $\partial B_1 \cap \partial B_2 = \emptyset$ which means no intersections, but the equation is satisfied. Did I miss something?

The correct statement probably should be the spheres $S(x_1, r_1)$ and $S(x_2, r_2)$ intersect iff $|r_1 - r_2| \leq |x_1 - x_2| \leq r_1 + r_2$. (With real dimensions at least $2$ - in $\mathbb{R}$ there are clearly counterexamples.)

Yes, of course for the sphere case you should also have the restriction @DavidGao states to avoid the non-intersection if one is "inside" the other one.

The correct statement should be the spheres $S(x_1, r_1)$ and $S(x_2, r_2)$ intersect iff $|r_1 - r_2| \leq \|x_1 - x_2\| \leq r_1 + r_2$, under the assumption that the real dimension of $X$ is at least $2$, i.e., if your normed space is over $\mathbb{C}$ then being nontrivial is enough, but if your normed space is over $\mathbb{R}$, then you need $\dim(X) \geq 2$ - in $\mathbb{R}$ there are clearly counterexamples (say, $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 1$, and $r_1 = r_2 = 1$).
For simplicity, I’ll write $d$ for the metric induced by the norm.
Necessity: Let $x \in S(x_1, r_1) \cap S(x_2, r_2)$, then by triangle inequality,
$$|r_1 - r_2| = |d(x, x_1) - d(x, x_2)| \leq d(x_1, x_2) \leq d(x, x_1) + d(x, x_2) = r_1 + r_2$$
Sufficiency: We prove first that the spheres are path-connected. Since all spheres are homeomorphic to each other via translation and scaling, it suffices to show the unit sphere $S(0, 1)$ is path-connected. Let $x, y \in S(0, 1)$. Consider the line segment:
$$f: [0, 1] \to X, \; f(\lambda) = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y$$
Note that $0 \in \text{ran}(f)$ implies $x = -\frac{1 - \lambda}{\lambda}y$ for some $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. Since $x$ and $y$ both have norm $1$, it must be the case that $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ and $x = -y$. Thus, unless $x = -y$, the following is a path from $y$ to $x$ on the unit sphere:
$$g: [0, 1] \to S(0, 1), \; g(\lambda) = \frac{f(\lambda)}{\|f(\lambda)\|}$$
Since $X$ has real dimensions at least $2$, there are more than $2$ points on the unit sphere, whence $x$ and $-x$ can also be connected by a path, by first going from $x$ to some $y$ that is neither $x$ nor $-x$, then going from $y$ to $-x$.
This proves all spheres are path-connected, so in particular connected. Now, in case $x_1 = x_2$, the assumptions ensure $r_1 = r_2$, and the result is obvious. So, we may assume $x_1 \neq x_2$.
Observe that $r_2 - r_1 \leq \|r_1 - r_2\| \leq \|x_1 - x_2\|$, so $r_1 \geq r_2 - \|x_1 - x_2\|$. We also have $\|x_1 - x_2\| \leq r_1 + r_2$, so $r_1 \geq \|x_1 - x_2\| - r_2$. Thus, $|r_2 - \|x_1 - x_2\|| \leq r_1$. Moreover, $r_1 - r_2 \leq \|r_1 - r_2\| \leq \|x_1 - x_2\|$, so $r_1 \leq r_2 + \|x_1 - x_2\|$.
Consider the function,
$$e: S(x_2, r_2) \to \mathbb{R}, \; e(x) = d(x, x_1)$$
Note that $x = x_2 + \frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|}(x_1 - x_2)$ is in $S(x_2, r_2)$, and furthermore,
$$\begin{split}
d(x, x_1) &= \|x_2 + \frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|}(x_1 - x_2) - x_1\|\\
&= |\frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|} - 1| \|x_1 - x_2\|\\
&= |r_2 - \|x_1 - x_2\||\\
&\leq r_1
\end{split}$$
We also have $y = x_2 - \frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|}(x_1 - x_2)$ is in $S(x_2, r_2)$, and furthermore,
$$\begin{split}
d(y, x_1) &= \|x_2 - \frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|}(x_1 - x_2) - x_1\|\\
&= (\frac{r_2}{\|x_1 - x_2\|} + 1) \|x_1 - x_2\|\\
&= r_2 + \|x_1 - x_2\|\\
&\geq r_1
\end{split}$$
Since $S(x_2, r_2)$ is connected and $e$ is continuous, the range of $e$ is connected and thus an interval. As $e(y) \geq r_1 \geq e(x)$, we thus have $r_1 \in \text{ran}(e)$, i.e., there exists $z \in S(x_2, r_2)$ s.t. $d(z, x_1) = r_1$, so $S(x_1, r_2) \cap S(x_2, r_2) \neq \varnothing$.
